# How to check if elements of std::vector<std::string> start with certain sub-string?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdstring, std

I have a very large `std::vector` `v` of type `std::vector<std::string> v`. Now I want to compare **which of the elements in the vector start with a certain substring** `str`. What is the fastest possible way to do that?

I was thinking of a for-loop that iteratively compares the start of each element of `v` with the substring `str`. I first tried

```
std::string substring = "bla";
for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    if (!strncmp(v[i].c_str(), substring.c_str(), substring.size())) 
    {
        std::cout << "Item found: " << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Which is [c](/questions/tagged/c) mixed with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and I am not happy with that.

What better alternatives are there?

Comment: Simply do this: `if ( v[i].substr(0, substring.size()) == substring ) { /* ... */ }` for the string comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write completely a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code.

If you want to find all the elements satisfying the condition, you can not avoid iterating through the entire vector.
But you could use better *[range-based `for-loop`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)* instead of index based loop to iterate through the vector, and check wether [`str.find(substring) == 0`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)(credits *[@PiotrSkotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki)*).

Here is the example code:
 **([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yL4fSQxRHsdziwo6))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::string substring{ "bla" };
    std::vector<std::string> vecString{ {"bllll"}, {"bllll"}, {"blasomething"} };
    // iterate through the vector by range based for-loop
    // here `auto` deduded to `std::string` as you have vector of strings(i.e. `vecString`)
    for (const auto& str : vecString)
    {
        if (str.find(substring) == 0) {
            std::cout << str << " is a match\n";
            // do something more with str
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Alternatively using [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), along with a lambda function you could write the following. Read more about the lambdas here: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) 
 **([See online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6owQz8dGduXV0wkI))**

```
#include <algorithm> // std::for_each

std::for_each(std::cbegin(vecString), std::cend(vecString), [&substring](const auto& str)
{
    if (str.find(substring) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << str << " is a match\n";
        // do something more with str
    }
});
```

---

If you are interested only the first match in the *vector of string* s, making use of standard algorithm [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as follows

```
#include <algorithm> // std::find_if

const auto iter = std::find_if(std::cbegin(vecString), std::cend(vecString),
    [&substring](const auto& str) {
        return str.find(substring) == 0;
    }
);
if (iter != std::cend(vecString))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You still need to loop. This will only return the first match.

Comment: @DimChtz Missed the part of "all the elements". Okay, then simply range based loop or `std::for_each`. Will update accordingly

Comment: Can you please add some comments to your code? I am not familiar with lines such as `for (const auto& str : vecString)` or `const auto check = [&substring](const auto& str)`. Thank you!

Comment: `std::basic_string::substr` creates a copy of the string which is inefficient in this case.  `return str.find(substring) == 0;` would be far better.

Comment: @JeJo That's why I verify that the substring was found at position `0`. See that `== 0` part ?

Comment: Why is the `elementString.size() >= substring.size()` part essential. I tried it without and it works just fine. Can you explain why it is necessary?

Comment: @Samuel However, I have updated the answer with Piotr's suggestion, which is better than I have posted earlier.

Comment: Do I need `str.find()` when I am only interested if the substring matches with the start of the string in the array?

Comment: @Samuel Yea, that is needed. Here we are checking whether the position of the *substring* is `0`. That means, at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @JeJo @Samuel calling `str.find()` for this task is very inefficient unless optimizer is very smart.

Comment: @ALX23z *very inefficient*, one can not say directly that: Why?-> Without benchmarking the all other possible solutions to question(including the `str.find()` one) with certain test cases(possibly from OP) for several builds by maximum optimisation enabled. That has to be verified before you say `str.find()` is inefficient compared to other answers(IMHO). You are most welcome to point out(maybe as another answer) *the best efficient way* .

Comment: @JeJo while compilers have grown quite good over the years, you surely leave a lot of shit behind for them to deal with. And what about debug mode? Do you forsake that mode as well? `string::find` is based on a complicated algorithm to avoid `O(NM)` complexity; don't expect much from compiler when dealing with sophisticated algorithms like that. Simplest and most efficient solution is `if(str.length()>= substring.length() && (str.compare(0,substring.length(),substring) == 0))`.

Comment: @ALX23z That looks promising: http://quick-bench.com/PuL3ggsdyADAUL47Al3SPKgHRog (hope I have done it correctly). I would suggest proving it as the answer so that future readers can benefit from it. I would be happy to up it. 

Answer (score 3):

If you have an unsorted container you can't get better than *O(n)* in time complexity, which means iterating over the whole container in a linear manner (i.e. for loop). If your container was sorted (ex. `std::set` instead of `std::vector`) you would get *O(log n)* which is a lot better (binary search).

Prior to C++17, I can't come up with a better solution than yours (since creating a substring via `std::string::substr` means copying the substring unnecessarily). However C++17 introduced `std::string_view` which doesn't do any copying. There should be no noticable performance difference with compiler optimizations enabled.

```
std::vector<std::string> v { "abcd", "abcdefg", "aaaabbbb", "abc", "ab"};
std::string_view query = "abc";

for (auto const& str : v) 
{
    if (str.size() < query.size())
        continue;

    auto probe = std::string_view(str).substr(0, query.size());
    if (query == probe)
        std::cout << "Item found: " << str << "\n";        
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/UoJmQi)

And here is the `std::set` version for the quicker search:

```
std::set<std::string> v { "abcd", "abcdefg", "aaaabbbb", "abc", "ab"};
std::string query = "abc";

for (auto it = v.lower_bound(query); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
    auto probe = std::string_view(*it).substr(0, query.size());
    if (query == probe)
        std::cout << "Item found: " << *it << "\n";     
    else
        break;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/lSsqjR)

Answer (score 3):

You can using c++20 [`std::string_view::start_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with):

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {...};
std::string_view prefix = "bla";
for (std::string_view sv : v)
    if (sv.starts_with(prefix))
        std::cout << "Item found: " << sv << std::endl;
```